# kable_styling() leads to disappearing table

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

For some reason, kable() works but whenever I pipe it into kable_styling(), the output is faulty. In the preview, I can briefly see the numerical data (for like a split second) before it disappears. It's just an empty table now.

The loaded packages are
library(gridExtra)
library(htmltools)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(sjPlot)
library(tidyverse)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue:

```
kable(iris[1:10,], "html", booktabs = T) %>% 
kable_styling(., full_width = TRUE, html_font = "arial")
```

In an R Notebook in Rstudio, code before the pipe gives an in-line table, but adding the second part causes the data in the table to vanish after a spit second as described.

Adding a further pipe to save_kable() does generate a plot in the saved file. Also running the code in an R script in Rstudio generates the graphic as expected. So presumably the problem is something to do with the RStudio interpretation of the in the context of a Notebook.